# Polymorphism and Function Overloading?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class, overloading

I have a `Base` class, and a `Derived` class of `Base`

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived: public Base{};
```

I want to make a function that accepts `Base*`, but has different functionality when passed a `Derived*`.

```
void myFunc(Base* base){
 std::cout << "myFunc(base)" << std::endl; 
}

void myFunc(Derived* derived){
 std::cout << "myFunc(derived)" << std::endl;
}
```

My problem is when I try to use polymorphism, the function doesn't behave as desired because I'm always passing `Base*`'s.

```
Base* base = new Base();
Base* derived = new Derived();

myFunc(base);
myFunc(derived);
```

Outputs:

```
myFunc(base)
myFunc(base)
```

Desired outputs:

```
myFunc(base)
myFunc(derived)
```

The reason I can't use casting like - `(Derived*)derived` - is because I'm using an array of `Base*`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base{};    
struct Derived: public Base{};

void myFunc(Base* base){
 std::cout << "myFunc(base)" << std::endl; 
}

void myFunc(Derived* derived){
 std::cout << "myFunc(derived)" << std::endl;
}

void myFunc(Base** bases, size_t count){
 for(auto i = 0; i < count; i++){
  myFunc(bases[i]);
 }
}

int main(){
 Base* bases[2];
 bases[0] = new Base();
 bases[1] = new Derived();

 myFunc(bases, 2);
}
```

The reason I can't make `myFunc` a virtual member function of base, is because I want to encapsulate `myFunc`'s functionality in a separate class to avoid a monolithic base class.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base{};

struct Derived: public Base{};

struct DoesStuff{
 void doStuff(Base* base){
  std::cout << "doStuff(base)" << std::endl; 
 }

 void doStuff(Derived* derived){
  std::cout << "doStuff(derived)" << std::endl;
 }

 void doStuff(Base** bases, size_t count){
  for(auto i = 0; i < count; i++){
   doStuff(bases[i]);
  }
 }
};

struct DoesOtherStuff{
 void doOtherStuff(Base* base){
  std::cout << "doOtherStuff(base)" << std::endl; 
 }

 void doOtherStuff(Derived* derived){
  std::cout << "doOtherStuff(derived)" << std::endl;
 }

 void doOtherStuff(Base** bases, size_t count){
  for(auto i = 0; i < count; i++){
   doOtherStuff(bases[i]);
  }
 }
};

int main(){
 Base* bases[2];
 bases[0] = new Base();
 bases[1] = new Derived();

 DoesStuff stuffDoer;
 DoesOtherStuff otherStuffDoer;

 stuffDoer.doStuff(bases, 2);
 otherStuffDoer.doOtherStuff(bases, 2);
}
```

How do I get `myFunc` to know a `Base*` is secretly a `Derived*`. I think I could use `typeid`, but I'm not sure that's the most appropriate solution. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you have to declare your functions as virtual. Keep in mind its better to pass a reference than a pointer

Comment: Try using a template and provide the appropriate specializations, instead of introducing ambiguity via `Base*` and `Derived*` pointer types.

Comment: @KostasRim There's no surrounding class for the functions in question. How should these be `virtual` actually?

Comment: A case for `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: A case for a redesign before `dynamic_cast`, any day

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if you want polymorphism you need virtual functions. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @KostasRim _Am i missing something ?_ Yes, templates and specializations as mentioned. And even with classes we have CRTP, which doesn't need `virtual`.

Comment: You need to think about the responsibilities of your classes. If you want a flat function to behave differently depending on the concrete type passed to it, then your base class needs to provide a service which the flat function can use; and the derived class can customise. This is _encapsulation_ - an important part of OO development. (imho understanding encapsulation and well designed class responsibilities is probably more important than polymorphism).

Comment: @CraigYoung In my real-world program, Base holds data with a few functions to manipulate that data, and myFunc is part of a separate class responsible for doing specific things to Bases. (As you said, for the sake of encapsulation) I want to avoid Base becoming a massive class full of many unrelated functions.

Comment: @WillyGoat What I'm trying to say is that you might want to carefully consider the appropriate services that Base should provide so that myFunc behaves correctly with various derived classes. After all, each Derived class is best "qualified" for the job of customising itself. (There are other options to avoid the bloat you refer to, but they have their own problems, so I'd give responsibility modelling a shot first to see how far you can get without them.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work via polymorphism is to do the following:

1. Create a virtual **member** function in the Base class that does what you want to do for Base classes.
2. Override that member function in the Derived class and have it do what you want for Derived classes.

That's the essence of polymorphism.  The reason it doesn't work for your non-member or free function is because they are both passed Base class pointers.

Comment: Let's add it's only the essence of _runtime_ (aka. _dynamic_) polymorphism. The overloads or template routes are also polymorphism, but not classical OOP polymorphism (I'd argue that the classic OOP style should be rare in C++, because typically other languages are more suited to that...)

Comment: That's fair.  But I don't agree with the very last part of your statement that is contained in parentheses.

Comment: What if `myFunc` is part of a class I have responsible for doing something to `Base` and `Derived`.
Right now I'm avoiding a problem of having dozens of unrelated functions inside of `Base`, and instead having classes that operate on arrays of `Base`

Comment: @WillyGoat This sounds like a classic double-dispatch issue, where you want to separate the representation of the objects from the algorithms that run on them.  That's exactly what the visitor pattern is for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: @ChrisHayden Interesting. I'm reading into it right now, thank you.